# Wijmo FlexGrid column to show enum string instead of ordinal

Tags: typescript, wijmo, wijmo5

How can I make the FlexGrid column to show enum string instead of ordinal. This should be achievable using some formatting. I can think of either using ItemFormatter for the grid or using CellTemplate.

Need to know what's the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue .I have used wijmo.grid.DataMap .
The following link is useful ,

`enter code here` http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo5/8brL80r8/